# OS X Server 10.8 Sending Email

Tags: postfix, email-server, mac-osx-server, osx-mountain-lion

I'm running a 10.8.5 OS X Server box, with mail running.  I'm using one of my local email accounts to send email to a hosted address I have.  This where it gets tricky.

Web is hosted internally.  Mail is hosted externally, for this target domain.  MX records are set properly.

- test from a gmail account gets to the intended target
- test from in-house email shows up as **sent** in the **smtp** log, but it doesn't show up in the webmail account on the host

The log entry on my mail server says the to is **, orig_to=, relay=dovecot, delay=0.08, delays=0.03/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)**

So the smtp server thinks both domains are on itself, which they are not.  Web DNS and mail DNS are different, and it's not checking the proper **DNS** for this **LAN**, which is outside the **LAN**.  I am not running **DNS** due to this sort of confusion, and I want to minimize my internal network configuration.

Yes, a bit confusing, even for the server.

And those test emails from  to  are lost.  There is no queue, so they're inside the server somewhere.  I'm not versed on **Postfix** commands.

Any advice how I can clear this up?  I don't mind the terminal, so any commands and insight truly appreciated how I can fix this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

OK, an update, which is an answer, I guess.

The server indeed has a user for that username (vhost usernames are still unique across multiple domains, which register as **username@example1.com** and **username@example2.com**), so I just forwarded incoming emails to another account.  That's why there was no queue and nothing outgoing, as it technically found its target.  There's no reason to have that account, but it's now acting as a proxy for **LAN** emails targeting that account.

All is good.